# Carrierwave: upload an image from vue front to rails api

Tags: vue.js, rails-api

I am not sure how to make the axios post for the image.

This is what my json object looks like.

```
{
 "id":20,
 "title":"pineapple",
 "text":"pineapple",
 "date":null,
 "created_at":"2019-03-23T01:42:48.142Z",
 "updated_at":"2019-03-23T01:42:48.142Z",
 "image":{
          "url":null
         }
 }
```

This is my image input from the Vue form.

```
<input  type="file" 
        id="file" 
        ref="myFiles" 
        class="custom-file-input" 
        @change="takeFile" 
        multiple>
```

Here is me trying to make sense of it.

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        blog: {
          title: '',
          content: '',
          link: ''
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submitArticle(blog) {
        console.log('blog.link', blog.link)
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/articles', {
          title: blog.title,
          text: blog.content,
          image: {
            url: blog.link 
          }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      },
      takeFile(event) {
        console.log(this.$refs.myFiles.files);
        this.blog.link = this.$refs.myFiles.files
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a link to the file in my [repo](https://github.com/Elijbet/Portfolio_App_2019/blob/master/vue_portfolio/src/components/Articles/Add_Articles.vue).

Comment: try this `takeFile(event) {
   let image= event.target.files[0]
   let reader = new FileReader()
   reader.readAsDataURL(image)
   reader.onload= e =>{
     this.blog.link = e.target.result
    }
}`  then add  `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }` in axios post request

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried but it didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `this.$refs.myFiles.files` returns an array of files. Change your method like this to set the file to `blog.link`:

```js
takeFile(event) {
  this.blog.link = this.$refs.myFiles.files[0]
}
```

Now to send file in your post request, you should use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```js
submitArticle(blog) {
  let formData = new FormData()
  formData.append("article[title]", blog.title)
  formData.append("article[text]", blog.content)
  formData.append("article[image]", blog.link)
  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/articles', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
},
```

Comment: This really helped. Thank you so much.